# .htaccess RewriteRule non-www to www without explicity specifying domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make a general rewrite rule to redirect all domain.com requests to www.domain.com.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-z-]+)\.([0-9a-z-]+])$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that this rewrite rule doesn't match anything. How can I change it? Thanks

Comment: This is not an especially simple task due to the structure that URLs can take. Obviously the code you have there will only pick up TLDs that have a single dot such as .com, .info, .org etc. and will not pick up .co.uk and so forth. By making that more dynamic though it is difficult not to pick up other subdomains. Your best bet is probably to use alternation to specify the TLDs to support i.e. \.(com|co\.uk|org), though this obviously isn't entirely dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that there’s an additional `]` in your `RewriteCond`’s pattern and that there is a `%` missing when referencing *HTTP_HOST* in `RewriteRule`’s substitution. So try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-z-]+)\.([0-9a-z-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And to cover Cags’ concerns a litte bit, you can also try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^./]+\.[^./]+$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.[^./]+\.[^./]+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !=www [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```